# Google Sitemap generation error magento version 1.9.0.1

Tags: magento-1.9

Today I tried to generate google sitemap on my site, through `admin panel > catalog > generate the sitemap.` after a moment it keeps displaying this error message in my browser 504 Gateway Time-out.

I have Magento version 1.9.0.1.

Comment: How long is "a moment"? 30 seconds? A minute?

Comment: After a minute of waiting it would result to 504 Gateway Time-out error.

Comment: Anything in your logs?

Comment: You need to increase php execution time and memory  limit